# R: fread multiple files with different decimal seperators

Tags: r, numeric, fread, separator

when reading a csv file via `fread` and using `colClasses` to read the columns as numerics I am having trouble with data that consists of numbers with commas instead of dots. Since the data files have different origins, some use "." and some use "," as decimal separator

```
dt <- data.table(a=c("1,4","2,0","4,5","3,5","6,9"),c=(10:14))
write.csv(dt,"dt.csv",row.names=F)
dcsv <- fread("dt.csv", colClasses = list(numeric = 1:2), dec = ",").
```

I have 2 problems:
I want to read both columns as numerics. So I tried using `dec = ","`. I now get an `error: Column number 2 (colClasses[[1]][2]) is out of range [1,ncol=1]` 
So I changed to `colClasses = list(numeric = 1)`, but don't quite understand this.

Still the first column turns out to be character type instead of numeric.

How could I also change `dec` to `.`and `,`, since I don't know in advance what type of decimal separator any of the hundreds of files uses. I tried a vector, but did not work out.  What am I missing? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not normal to have a file with 2 different types of numeric separator.

You should question the source of the file first thing.

Nevertheless, if you have such a file, the correct way to read it is with the variables with a comma separator as a string then to convert it to a numeric.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(a=c("1,4","2,0","4,5","3,5","6,9"),c=(10:14))
write.csv(dt,"dt.csv",row.names=F)
dcsv <- fread("dt.csv", dec = ".")
dcsv[, a:= as.numeric(gsub("\"", "", gsub(",", ".", a)))]
```

If you don't know if your variable is with a comma or a dot separator, you can loop over your variable to test if the variable is a string with only number and comma and convert only the ones fulfilling that condition.

Comment: I did not express my self clearly, sorry about that. I meant different types of numeric separator in different files, which I want to read in via `fread`. So file1 uses `.`, file2 uses `,` etc. Thanks for your answer!